# Martingality of a Doleans-Dade exponential local martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

A paper I read recently seems to make the following statement: if $\gamma_t$ is a progressively measurable process, and that $\exp\left(\int_0^T\gamma_s dW_s\right) \in L^p$ for some $p>1$, then the exponential local martingale $$\exp\left(\int_0^T\gamma_sdW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^T\gamma^2_s ds\right)$$ is a true martingale.

This was not stated explicitly as a result. Instead $\exp\left(\int_0^T\gamma_s dW_s\right)$ is assumed to be in $L^p$ and the author applied the change of measure without further explanation.

Does it actually hold true that $L^p$ integrability of $\exp\left(\int_0^T\gamma_s dW_s\right)$ implies the martingality of $\mathcal{E}\left[\int \gamma_s dW_s\right]$? And if so, can you please give a reference for the result?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming $\int_0^T\Bbb E[ \gamma_s^2]ds<\infty$ you know that $\int_0^t \gamma_s dW_s$ is a martingale. Since $x \mapsto e^{px}$ is convex it follows $\exp\big(p\int_0^t \gamma_sdW_s \big)$ is a submartingale. Then you apply Doob's $L^p$ inequality and you get $\sup_{t \le T} \exp\big(\int_0^t \gamma_sdW_s \big) \in L^p$. This then easily shows that your local martingale $\mathcal E[\int \gamma dW]$ is of Class DL so it is a martingale. (Sorry in advance if there's a mistake here; my stochastic calculus is rusty)

Comment: Also I want to remark that it is not sufficient to just assume that $\exp\big (\int_0^T \gamma dW -\frac12 \int_0^T \gamma^2ds\big ) \in L^p$. Basically I think that a counterexample is given by the solution of $dU = U^2 dB$ with $U_0=1$, which is the reciprocal of a 3D Bessel process. Note that $U$ is the exponential martingale of its own stochastic logarithm $\int_0^t U_s^{-1}dU_s = \int_0^t U_sdW_s$, however a computation shows that $\Bbb E[U_t^2] \leq Ct^{-1}$ so $U$ cannot be a martingale.

Comment: Correction: remove all instances of “p” from the second sentence of my first comment

Comment: @Shalop: I think having just $E[\exp(\frac12\int_0^T\gamma_s^2ds)] < +\infty$ should be enough to prove that $\exp\big (\int_0^T \gamma_s dW_s -\frac12 \int_0^T \gamma_s^2ds\big )$ is a martingale. This can be weakened as well by assuming that $E[\exp(\frac12\int_0^T\gamma_sdW_s)] < +\infty$.

Comment: @Sesame that sounds like novikov. As I recall it’s a lot harder to prove and requires an optional stopping argument (rather than a simple application of doob’s inequality like the p>1 case).